# Renaming Android package name using Android Studio

Tags: android, rename

I Was Created an android application with package name of **com.example.******.sample** . I need to refactor the package name into **org.newOrg.*******.sample** . I was already tried refactor method. But its parent "com" was not changed into "org" . Tell me any solution to refactor the entire package name.

Thanks in advance

Comment: press `Shif+f6` then do rest of things.

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package

Comment: Please see this link.it's helpful for you:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848046/how-to-change-package-name-in-android-studio

Comment: Perfect and Clear demo @Naveen . Thanks

Comment: Thanks Rustam and Pranav

Comment: Its Very Well Answered Here...
try checking out..
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092698/6915572

Comment: [3 Fantastic ways to rename android app package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857285/renaming-package-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This modification needs three steps :

1. Change the package name in the manifest
2. Refactor the name of your package with right click -> refactor -> rename in the tree view, then Android studio will display a window, select "rename package"
3. Change manually the application Id in the build.gradle file : android / defaultconfig / application ID
   Then clean / rebuild the project

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600329/how-do-i-rename-the-android-package-name

Comment: Good Solution @ Gaurav Polekar

Comment: The above all solutions little bit same and works much better than other collapsing solutions. From the above all solutions, **Naveen's** explanation is pretty clear to see. Thanks to all who share different ways to renaming the package name.

Answer (score 5):

In Android Studio, you can do this by following these 4 steps:

1) Click on the little gear icon on Project Pane

2) Uncheck the `Compact Empty Middle Packages` option

3) Now you can rename each `package` by right-click & then `refactor` it, remember to select `Rename Package` on popup rather `Rename Directory`

4) Update the `package` in `build.gradle`

5) And update `google-services.json` is you are using it (i.e. FireBase).

Comment: Point no 2) save my life (:

Answer (score 1):

click on Settings in the project window uncheck the `Compact Empty Middle Packages`

It will separate the app package and you can rename it one after another.Also change the App Id inside build.gradle under defaultConfig section

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.foocomp.android"

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace function like click right on project main folder and click replace with choose. Then you can replace package name. I used it more times and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin "Android Package Renamer", it is available on Android Studio Marketplace and Intellij IDEA. It can complete several cases, and one of them contains your case.

### This plugin can rename packages in android project, here are a few specific cases (it can do more)::

- com.android.example -> org.nickseven.product
- com.android.example -> org.nickseven
- com.android.example -> org.nickseven.product.native
- com.android.etc.nick.d -> org.android.otd.nick.d
- ....etc

### What you need to do is download it and use the following:

- Open Your Project.
- Click -> File -> Rename Package
- Input the Package you want to change.
- Click OK.
- Sync Project with Gradle Files or Invalidate Caches

You can see the [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75362772/13753492) here and the official github repo [here](https://github.com/nguyenphuc22/Android-Package-Renamer) for more detailed instructions.